# refrescar valor de un select depues de regitrar usando boostraValitation

Tags: php, html, ajax

estoy usando php para llenar un select cuando se cargar la pagina.

```
<div class="form-group inputGroupContainer">
                        <label class="control-label" for="text">LOTE Y VIAJE:</label>
                        <div class="input-group input-group-lg" style="border: solid 1px rgb(206, 206, 206); border-top-left-radius:6px; border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;">
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow" data-style="btn-default" data-live-search="true" title="-- SELECCIONE LOTE Y VIAJE --" data-size="8" name="newinputLoteViaje" id="newLoteViaje" readonly required>

                                <?php

                                    $tabla2=4;
                                    $fkcodlotep=4;
                                    $referencia = ControMP::ctrMostrarlt($tabla2, $fkcodlotep);

                                    foreach ($referencia as $key => $value) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$value["cod"].'">'.'LOTE PIKÚ: '.$value["lote_piku"]." VIAJE:".$value["viaje"].'</option>';
                                    }

                                ?>
                            </select>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-maxcdn"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

lo cual funciona perfectamente, pero el problem es que estoy registrando mis datos atravez de ajax, entonces necesito que tambien se actualicen esos datos del select sin necesidad de recargar la pagina.

pero podria refrescar ese select depues de registrar el dato?

Answer (score 0):

debido a que estoy usando el plugin booststrap-select, la solucion que encontre fue la siguiente.

si los datos se registraron correctamente.

es decir si la repuesta que recibo es ok.

entonces ejecuto el siguiente metodo.

capturo el id del select, capturo el valor de ese select que se registro.

```
var idlote=$("#lote_fk").val();

$('#remove-example').find('[value='+idlote+']').remove();//elimino ese valor
  $('#remove-example').selectpicker('refresh');//y lo renderizo para que me actualice la lista
```

y listo todo sin recargar la pagina.